# New to Android, need custom layout similar to AbsoluteLayout

Tags: android, layout

I've been looking into creating a custom layout based on ViewGroup, and I get (I think) the concept on which layouts are based. Some of it, anyway.

It seems that the basic idea is

- first ask all your child views how big they want to be - in onMeasure()
- calculate a layout based on that
- position them all based on their desired sizes - in onLayout()

It's a bit like a web page layout, I suppose.

However, I don't want to do that at all. Based on the available screen real estate (x/y px)  I have a whole load of child views (various text, button, freeform graphics) that I need to define the dimensions of, set text sizes for, and then position. Ie I am not remotely interested in how big they would like to be, I want to tell them how big they will be and where they will be.

There is (was) an AbsoluteLayout that does something similar, but it is depreciated.

Since the layout is totally tied in with the children (completely fixed number for the job) and screen size, I am proposing to:

- Create my own custom layout sub-classing ViewGroup
- somewhere early on - possibly in its onCreate()? - create all the children (I know exactly what is needed)
- in onMeasure() ignore everything the children want, although I suspect I have to call measureChild() to an avoid exception by making sure setMeasuredDimension() is called everywhere, and calculate the layout (sizes, positions) based on the dimensions passed in the width/heightMeasureSpecs
- in onLayout() just tell all the children how it is going to be ("you are here and this big")
- since I am not interested in what the children want sizewise, just absorb any layoutRequest() callback and do nothing in it

However, this does seem conceptually to go against how Android thinks layouts should be done - but it is what I need.

So my question is - is it a viable scheme?

Answer (score 1):

You can get source of the `AbsoluteLayout` and adapt it to your needs. If `AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated, there will be a reason for that, and if that reason doesn't apply to you, you are free to do whatever you like.

Comment: Have you ever used `AbsoluteLayout` and show the problems it causes while app is for multiple screen resolutions?

Comment: @PareshMayani, please read the answer carefully. I am in no way supporting the use of deprecated classes, but if the OP **wants** to use it for whatever reason that can justify the use irrespective of the short comings, why should someone limit him/her? And what makes you **assume** that the OP wants to support multiple screen resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, and AbsoluteLayout, while deprecated, can still be used up to ICS.

You may need to rethink your UI design though - it's deprecated for a reason.

Comment: To answer this and the previous comment. What I really have is a view which has areas with different properties in terms of what they display (text, graphics etc) and also in terms of what if anything they can respond to (touches etc). This could all be done in one view - and in the Windows platform it is being ported from, that is what was done (Windows document / view architecture). However it struck me it was neater maybe and more modular to split this view into multiple sub-views, each with their own characteristics and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exactly tell the children what size to be, when you call onMeasure, you pass the dimensions with the MeasureSpec mode EXACTLY. They should obey this, and you shouldn't have to do any hacky workarounds to ignore their requested size.

See the [View.MeasureSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html) encodings. The (int,int) passed to onMeasure are supposed to be measureSpec encoded.

Comment: Thanks, yes, seen that. Other questions related:

Comment: Whoops. (1) I see onMeasure() gets called with measure specs - can be excatly, at_most or undefined. What is it that determines which my (top level) custom layout will get called with? (2) I can just create my custom layout from the activity (onCreate() I assume), using the constructor that passes in width and height. Since this is like the constructor that gets called with attributes from XML if one does it that way, do I assume that the width and height can be set to such things as FILL_PARENT?